# What type of outlet could this be in picture?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

Does anyone know what type of outlet this is? I'm thinking it has to do with an old antenna but not sure. Found on a family member's house and they weren't sure.

[image: unknown outlet]

Comment: Looks like an old land-line phone jack to me.

Comment: What type of cable is coming out of the bottom. also, does it go anywhere that might indicate its use?

Comment: What location is this (what part of the world)? Is this inside or outside the house?  And @PaulLogan, I never seen a phone jack like that - where are you?

Comment: Land lines were usually 4 pin antennas were 2 pin. The cable rg57? The cable type could suggest the use also.

Comment: @JPhi168 This is in Connecticut, United States

Comment: I think it's an old receptacle for twinax or a ladder line. The ham site will probably be more useful than home improvement. (Or at least able to rule out if it's for a radio antenna.)

Answer (score 4):

That is an optical coupler from a utility meter to allow a meter reader to electronically read the meter with a handheld data collection device.  They are usually on the meter itself, but in this case the meter must be inconvenient to access so a remote coupler was used.

Answer (score 3):

It looks exactly like the interface for an ANSI 12.18 optical port (32 mm diameter), used for serial (RS232 or USB) interface between 'smart' watt-hour meter and the reader/monitor/programming device. Typical probe attaches to the port with internal magnet or two. One hole would be an LED (opto-transmitter) and other hole is photo-transistor (receiver).

[Link: to photo of one on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004HJ6SOM)